# Is" Look, there are standing two policemen" an existence sentence or an inverted sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction

> Look, there are standing two policemen.

I think this sentence is an inverted sentence, its natural order should be "Look, two policemen are standing there".

However, if I parsed it as an existence sentence, it should be :"Look, there are two policemen standing".

So how to parse this sentence?

Comment: The writer probably used a "poetic license".

Comment: To simplify, I'd parse it this way - Look, [there are standing] [two policemen]

Comment: @MaulikV Like what you parse, how to understand this sentence?

Comment: **"Look, two policemen are standing there".** This is correct. The fronting of a place adverb, there, allows the verb, are standing, to invert.

Answer (score 1):

Let's break down this sentence.

We start with the imperative 'Look,' and that will always stay where it is, so we can forget that.

The subjects are the policemen, described with a quantity 'two' and said to be 'standing'. The important word here is 'standing'. Treat it like an adjective:

*Post modifying:* The policemen are **standing**.
*Pre modifying:* The **standing** policemen.

*Then we add the 'two':*

The two policemen are standing.
The two standing policemen.

*Then we add their location. The 'there' can be added at the end or at the beginning, leaving us with many more possible and correct versions:*

There, the two policemen are standing.
There are two policemen standing.
The two policemen are standing there.
There are the two standing policemen.
The two standing policemen are there.

*Sadly, 'there are standing two policemen' is not very natural. Any of the others I've listed above are more natural and all equally correct. This isn't a guide for every statement, but it shows how many ways you can juggle words about here.*

Comment: Should I be nervous...? :D